# ReactJS. How to get states of elements inside react component

Tags: reactjs

Help me please to get states of elements inside react component or other some custom features with information which I need. Every of td tags contains react component Block1.
Simplified code structure below

```
class Block2 extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <Block1 />
          </td>
          <td>
            <Block1 />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )}}
```

Block1 - react component which contain div elements.
Block2 is inside component Block3. How to get states of Block1 from Block3 by  click on some button?
Now, I can get list of Block1 and may see props, but I can't see states. Or I can get DOM td elements and see children classNames (which I looking for in states) but I can't see props...

Comment: Do you mean you want to access parent's state in child components ??

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use libraries like Redux, you have to do the following to solve your problem:
Store the state inside `Block3` and not `Block1`. Then pass any function that changes this state as `props` from `Block3` to `Block2` to `Block1`. When any change occurs in `Block1`, call this function. The pattern should be:

```
class Block3 {
  changeState(value) {
    this.setState({ stateValue: value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Block2 changeState={this.changeState}/>
    )
  }
}

class Block2 extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <Block1 changeState={this.props.changeState} />
          </td>
          <td>
            <Block1 changeState={this.props.changeState} />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )}}


class Block1 {
  changeHandler(ev) {
    this.props.changeState(ev.target.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.changeHandler}/>
    )
  }
}
```

If you really want to access the child `state` inside a parent component, consider using `refs`:

```
class Block2 {
  render() {
    return <Block1 ref={ (childComponent) => { this.block1Child = childComponent; } } />;
    // Now you may use this.block1Child to access child component's state eg: this.block1Child.setState({})
  }
}
```

EDIT: My solution after seeing your code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Hall.css';

class HallCol extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        chair_cls:'chair-default'
      };
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
      let chair_cls = null;
      if(this.state.chair_cls==="chair-default") {
        chair_cls = 'chair-sold';
        this.props.updateCount(1, this.props.seat_number);
      } else {
        chair_cls = 'chair-default';
        this.props.updateCount(-1, this.props.seat_number);
      }

      this.setState({
        chair_cls: chair_cls
      });
    }

    render(){
      return(
            <div className={this.state.chair_cls} onClick={this.handleClick}>
              <div className="backrest">
                  <p>{this.props.seat_number}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="armrest-left">
              </div>
              <div className="armrest-right">
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.genRow = this.genRow.bind(this);         // this is method binding
  }

  genRow() {
    var rows = this.props.rows;
    return rows.map(function(v, i) {
      var tmp = v.map(function(v2, j) {
        return (
          <td key={'td' + i + '_' + j} className='chair-cell' >
            {v2}
          </td>
        );
      });

      return (
        <tr key={'tr' + i}>
          {tmp}
        </tr>
      )
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="hall-grid" >
        <tbody>
          {this.genRow()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class Hall extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var rows_num = this.props.rows;
    var cols_num = this.props.cols;

    this.AddRow = this.AddRow.bind(this);
    this.updateSeats = this.updateSeats.bind(this);

    var row = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows_num; i++) {
      var col = [];
      for (var k = 0; k< cols_num; k++) {
          col.push(<HallCol row = {i+1} seat_number = {k+1} updateCount={this.updateSeats} />);  // bind the passed function to parent
      }
      row.push(col);
    }
    this.state = {
      rows: row,
      bookedSeats: [],
      count: 0
    };
  }

  AddRow() {
    let newRows = this.state.rows;
    newRows.push([0, 0]);
    this.setState({rows: newRows});
  }
  updateSeats(val, seat_number) {
    let bookedSeatsUpdated;
    if( val === 1 ) {
      bookedSeatsUpdated = this.state.bookedSeats.concat(seat_number);
    } else {
      bookedSeatsUpdated = this.state.bookedSeats;
      let index = bookedSeatsUpdated.indexOf(seat_number);
      bookedSeatsUpdated.splice(index,1);
    }
    this.setState({
      bookedSeats: bookedSeatsUpdated,
      count: this.state.count + val
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hall">
        <Table rows={this.state.rows} />
        <button className = "btn-default" onClick={() => {
            alert(this.state.count + 'seats : ' + this.state.bookedSeats);
          } }>
            TOTAL SOLD
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Hall;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I just want to access the child state. I try set refs as you advised, but can get state just one component. How to get states of all components? Block1 I put inside table  
    `code` 
    var row = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows_num; i++) {
      var col = [];
      for (var k = 0; k< cols_num; k++) {
          col.push(<Block1 row = {i+1} seat_number = {k+1}  ref={(childComponent) => { this.Block1Child = childComponent; } }/>);
      }
      row.push(col);
    }
    this.state = {
      rows: row
    };
    `code`

Comment: And try get states
  `code`
   countSold(e){
    this.state.rows.map(function(row){
        row.map(function(col){
            console.log(col);
        });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="hall">
        <Table rows={this.state.rows} />
        <button className = "btn-default" onClick={(e)=>this.countSold(this)}>
            TOTAL SOLD
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  `code`

Comment: I said you _can_ use `refs`, but it is deprecated. For your code, passing the function as `props` like in my answer is sufficient. If you run into any problem on that end, let me know

Comment: I catch your idea and make dozen attempts to implement this. But I just started to study React and most likely not correctly described the structure of components in my code. I will be very grateful if you look at the real code on Git with my last try. [link](https://github.com/FarawaySlv/tickets/blob/master/src/Hall.js)

Comment: Ok I see ur code.. What do u want done ?  
I see you are not binding your class methods at all. I need you to read this completely: http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/

Comment: I've updated my answer... let me know if it worked by accepting my answer or else comment here :)  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but that's not exactly what I need. It's code for ticket sales in the theater hall(I decided to use this task to study the React). I need to calculate not only how many seats sold,  but also know which ones. And in future each element will have not only the status default/sold, but can also be reserved or other. I want to get array of all elements with data: row and col - I get them from props, status default/sold/other. I will try to use children(but I don't see them now :(  ) or ReactDOM. If I have any positiv result I'll write there :).

Comment: I've updated my answer one last time, in order to get which seats have been booked. The thing is you can extend the logic to include and store any details you want, including all that you mentioned. It's all logical and the React pattern follows the above code. Make sure that React `state` stores info that is exclusive to that component.

Comment: P.S. I strongly recommend using [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). It's not at all difficult to learn and implement, and as your application grows larger, you will understand it is difficult to store all data inside of React components. Redux goes hand-in-hand with React, and if you are learning React now, you will eventually learn Redux soon. So learn now :)

Comment: Thanks, Dane. I will follow your advice!

Comment: Good luck! You can come back any time for doubts, but make sure you've done your research before! You should also consider closing this question by accepting an answer, otherwise it may remain open.

Comment: I got acquainted with Redux and I am sure that this is exactly what I need! Thanks a lot one more time for your advice!

Comment: Dane, I try work with Redux. If you can look please my new problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363729/react-redux-listen-to-store-changes