# React-Redux. Listen to store changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How to trace changes in store from this component. In the external component `Menu`, I select the menu item and dispatch to store as parameter `content`. Depending on what I chose, I need to substitute the contents of the following component:

```
class WorkSpace extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        content: this.props.mainStore.content
      }
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className = "workspace">
          //some content
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(
  state => ({
    mainStore: state
  }),
  dispatch =>({})
)(WorkSpace);
```

Comment: Pls add code for your reducer also. What is shape of your state tree ?

Comment: all code there https://github.com/FarawaySlv/tmpro/tree/master/src . I use the following architecture: MainPanel contain components Header, Content and Footer. Then inside Content  we can see components Menu - where we will choose some content for WorkSpace and WorkSpace. Menu tree in file main_menu.js. I can change my store parameter "content" from Menu but I can't  subscribe on this changes in WorkSpace. May be this is wrong architecture? Reducer for changing "content" in file actionCreators.js.

Comment: Your package.json doesn't seem to contain redux or react-redux ??

Comment: On Git my working sample, I don't know why redux and react-redux don't exist in  this file. I install them again and now this libraries are visible in package.json.